# Reference Material for Multvariate Analysis with Different Probability Distributions

Tags: multivariate-analysis, references

I'm interested in multivariate probability distributions with different sub-distributions. Say I've collected two metrics in a population, and we then  had a two dimensional probability distribution:

> **X1 ~ Normal(U, V) and X2 ~ Poi(Lambda)**

Notice how these two variables come from different probability distributions. I've been having trouble finding reference material for multivariate analysis where the dimensions come from different distributions.

For example: the Wischart distribution works well when the variables all come from chi-square distributions. Does anyone have any reference material for probability distributions where the sub-distributions are not the same?

Comment: What is "sub-distribution"? Did you mean *marginals*?

Comment: Hmm I suppose so

Comment: So, will your joint distribution be something like $(x_1,x_2)\sim f(u,v,\lambda)?$

Comment: Yeah, that would be it!

Comment: Is that still a Copula? They may or may not be related variables. (I don't know yet - but I do know that one follows a Poisson and another follows a Gaussian)

Comment: The best way to understand copulas is by example. For instance, if you code in MATLAB, look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/copulafit.html) example. You can find these in any language these days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "sub-dsitributions" in your question you mean *[marginals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution)*, then read about [copulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)).

The idea's that if you know the marginal distributions, then for any joint distribution there's an object called *copula*, which links the marginals to the joint distribution. It's like a functional, whose inputs are marginal distributions, and the output is the joint.

It's an elegant construct, the only issue is that you usually don't know which copula is the right one to use. So, you end up using the one you like and hope that it's the one.

Comment: Interesting! I would have never found that out. What a cool word too!

Comment: Is the Wishart distribution a type of Copula?

Comment: The distribution is not a copula. So, no Wishart is not a copula. The copula is a construct that links univariates into a joint distribution.

Comment: Hm, I don't quite understand: we can express the Wischart as marginal probabilties (one for each dimension) - hence I believe it could be expressed as a Copula.

Comment: If there another term, in the case that the "sub-distributions" are somehow related?

Comment: Yes, that's what Sklar's theorem says, that there's got to be a copula for Wishart distribution, but Wishart distribution itself is not a copula.